# Почему через консоль создаются файлы .swp?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vim, sudo

`sudo mkdir /var/www/site.local/publick_html` Создаём папку для сайта

`sudo vi /var/www/site.local/publick_html/index.php` Создаём файл

Через консоль эти 2 команды начинают "Глючить" - https://yadi.sk/i/L4-Cg-jizjbmJ

и сами к названию файла приписывается .swp , я особо не умею пользоваться такими файлами подкачками, да и не надо оно мне. Как это устранить?

Консоль также подвисает после прописывания этих команд

На сервере чистая ubuntu 16.04 + LAMP

=============================================================

**Редакт1*** Установил vim по мануалу, но это не помогло, дело в том, что при вводе любой команды vim или nano, консоль очень странно себя ведет,ничего нельзя вводить после этого. Я использую Bitvise ssh client , но вроде дело не в нем. От безысходности установил десктопный gvim, но я так понял, в нем нет встроенной консоли?)

Comment: 1. на ваш вопрос (напомню: «Почему через консоль создаются файлы .swp?») ответ дан. 2. если у вас есть другой вопрос, задайте его пожалуйста, с помощью соответствующей кнопки в правом верхнем углу страницы. 3. текст лучше приводить в виде текста, а не картинки. 4. если необходима картинка, её следует добавить непосредственно в вопрос.

Comment: По сути я не решил проблему, файлы .swp также создаются, чтобы прописать корректно вашу команду которая "решает" проблему мне необходимо запустить vim из консоли, и уже на этом этапе не ясно как поступить

Comment: редактор для такого примитива и не нужен. `$ echo "set noswapfile" >> ~/.vimrc`

Comment: да и вообще swap-файлы *vim*-а — это полезный и нужный компонент программы. то, что их существование вас так сильно смутило, дело, конечно, ваше. я же просто ответил на ваш вопрос по этому поводу. // создайте, пожалуйста, новый вопрос, в котором сформулируйте вашу проблему. с учётом пунктов, изложенных в моём первом комментарии.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

файл с дополнительным суффиксом `.swp` [создаёт программа *vim*](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/recover.html#swap-file).

помимо того, что он служит неким признаком, показывающим, что редактируемый файл (который без этого суффикса) в данный момент уже редактируется, в него (в файл с доп. суффиксом) ещё и записываются изменения, которые пока не сохранены, что позволяет восстановить эти изменения после, например, краха программы.

чтобы такой файл с суффиксом `.swp` не создавался рядом с редактируемым файлом, можно:

- либо вообще отключить создание swap-файла, [добавив в `vimrc` команду](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27swapfile%27)

  ```
  set noswapfile
  ```
- либо указать *vim*-у создавать его где-нибудь в домашнем каталоге пользователя, переопределив [значение переменной `directory`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27directory%27) (в том же `vimrc`), где перечисляются через запятую приоритетные места расположения таких файлов.

  например:

  ```
  set directory=~/.vim/backup,.,/tmp
  ```

  здесь сначала *vim* попробует создать swap-файл в каталоге `~/.vim/backup`, если не удалось (каталого не существует или недоступен для записи), то в том же каталоге, где и редактируемый файл — `.`, а если и там не удалось, то в `/tmp`.

---

в вашем случае программа *vim* запускается от имени пользователя `root`, соответственно менять надо `vimrc`, находящийся в домашнем каталоге этого пользователя — `/root/.vimrc` (см. ниже уточнение), ну и, если в конфигурации укажите, например, каталог `~/.vim/backup` для хранения swap-файлов, то этот каталог надо будет создать:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /root/.vim/backup
```

---

#### уточнение

какой именно каталог будет считаться домашним для программ, выполняемых с помощью программы `sudo`, зависит от настроек программы `sudo`. проверить можно, например, так:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo $HOME'
```

Answer (score 1):

Судя по вашему вопросу и скриншоту к нему, вы не пользовались текстовым редактором *vi* (или его продвинутой версией *vim*). Попробуйте использовать более привычный редактор, например входящий в ubuntu *nano*:

```
sudo       nano       /var/www/site.local/publick_html/index.php
^^^^       ^^^^       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
запустить  редактор   с именем файла
от root    (или др.
           программу)
```

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня команды nano или vim работают очень странно после них ничего нельзя ввести, https://yadi.sk/i/0Kf3N-q-znMr6

Comment: команды _nano_ или _vim_ открывают **консольный** текстовый редактор. Если вы просто хотите создать файл выполняйте `touch`.